# Blender: border rendering is not supported by sequencer

Tags: blender

Im using blender to edit a video and when i try to render it, it comes up with the error: border rendering is not supported by sequencer.
Using blender 2.80

Comment: In 2.80 the render border option was renamed to [render region](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html#render-region), you can clear it by pressing Alt-B in the 3d viewport or turn it off in the [render dimensions panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/settings.html#dimensions-panel).

Answer (score 15):

Disabling Render Region fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 8):

Turning off **border rendering** (**render region** blender 2.8) in **Rendering** -> **Properties** -> **Output properties**
fixed it for me.

[image]

I recall playing with menus and the hypothesis is that I checked it somewhere along the way to cause that problem in the first place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: interesting at what time the bot was deployed...

Answer (score 2):

I cant comment yet bc of reputation apparently, so I guess I have to leave my comment behind here. I do have an answer but I'm not sure if it is a correct one.

I had the same problem, and I think i fixed it by unchecking the sequencer box under Post processing in the same tab as where you edit the format and encoding etc. But now that it does let me render my video (just a picture with audio under it) the render result is audio only? Could be a seperate problem or part of this solution, idk. Would unchecking that box help for you?

Comment: that fixed the problem but now when i try to render it the video shows up with a gray screen and thats it.

Comment: Oh. looks like my problem solving really is as bad as it sounds. I fixed my issue by redoinhg the entire thing and then when I hit render blender wasnt whing anymore. But now i see someone smarter has answered the question more effectively, so

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me on the same exact issue was the Crop to Render setting you can check or uncheck. I checked it and voila! I can render again. Thought that might help someone. It is under the Output tab and it is right below Render Region setting.